# Installing SQL Server Tools

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssdt, ssdt-bi

In order to set up an SSAS system, I am having to install Visual Studio (SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence) but when I adding this to the instance, it says it has failed the rule "Same Architecture installation", and that I have to match the new installation CPU architecture with the CPU architecture with the instance.

The instance I'm trying to link to is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) running on Windows 7. The SSDT installation is Visual Studio 2013.

I'm not sure how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

[g2server](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2293226/g2server) wrote in answer to the question [64 bit Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992846/440595) on Stack Overflow:

> As the others have said, there is only a 32 bit version.
>
> The important thing is, if you’re running an x64-based SQL instance (64-bit), make sure to select “New Instance” on the Installation Type page, and NOT “Add features to an existing instance”. Not doing so will cause it to error out.

---

<sub>*Community Wiki answer to document the solution on Stack Overflow found by [Dave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/70109/dave)*</sub>